# Unable to install prettytable in anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, prettytable

I want to install `prettytable` package in anaconda. 
To install this package with conda I have run:

`conda install -c synthicity prettytable`

and received the following error:

```
(base) C:\Users\hp>conda install -c synthicity prettytable
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - anaconda==5.2.0=py36_3
  - prettytable
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

I've no idea what conflict is it. and couldn't find any solution to this problem. Can someone please help me?

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear - there is a conflict between the anaconda package and the prettytable package. You need to create a new environment that does not include the anaconda package to be able to install the prettytable package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run Anaconda prompt as administrator and  run this command

> pip install PrettyTable

for window users only.

Comment: I would suggest to install PTable, it's a fork copy of prettytable, but have more feature.

Answer (score 4):

Try one of the following

1) conda install -c conda-forge prettytable
2) conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 prettytable

first one worked for me.